# Parsing string, date and time from a user defined sentence in android application

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an android application in which i want to parser the date, time and string that is what Natty do is exactly needed for me. I have tried in eclipse IDE. I have manually added the following jar files.

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
antlr-runtime-3.2.jar
backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
commons-codec-1.5.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
ical4j-1.0.2.jar
stringtemplate-3.2.jar
```

And i have followed the instructions given in Natty website.
That is in POM file. i have added the dependency as

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.joestelmach</groupId>
  <artifactId>natty</artifactId>
  <version>0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

and
added the following in main java file.

```
import com.joestelmach.natty.*;
Parser parser = new Parser();
List groups = parser.parse("the day before next thursday");
for(DateGroup group:groups) {
List dates = group.getDates();
int line = group.getLine();
int column = group.getPosition();
String matchingValue = group.getText();
String syntaxTree = group.getSyntaxTree().toStringTree();
Map parseMap = group.getParseLocations();
boolean isRecurreing = group.isRecurring();
Date recursUntil = group.getRecursUntil();
}
```

I have imported three libraries.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
```

Now i am getting an error in this line.

for(DateGroup group:groups)

Error:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to DateGroup.

Please suggest me some solutions for this.

Comment: I have added the Parser class under onCreateOptionsMenu function.

Comment: Or please suggest me some other solutions for me to parse the date,time and string from a sentence. For example, consider the following sentence "Lets go for lunch on July 17th 2016 at 1 pm", from this i need to extract Date:17th July 2016, time 1 pm and string : Lets go for lunch.

Comment: List<DateGroup> groups = parser.parse("the day before next thursday");
for(DateGroup group:groups) {
    //...
}  I got solution solved